# What code is needed to enter the generated number? c#

Tags: c#

```
        int plhp = 100;
        int plmp = 100;
        if (plhp > 101) { plhp = 100; }
        if (plmp > 101) { plmp = 100; }
        int zenhp = 500;
        if (zenhp > 501) { zenhp = 500; }
        Random rdn = new Random();
                while (plhp > 0 && zenhp > 0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Your move?");
                    string action = Console.ReadLine();
                    if (action == "attack")
                    {
                        zenhp -= rdn.Next(10, 55);
                        Console.WriteLine(name + "attacked Zen.");
                        Console.WriteLine("Zen has taken " + #Some code# + " damage!");
                    }
                 }
```

My question is, what code should I enter at **#Some code#** so that the exact number that is generated at the **rdn.Next(10, 55)** will appear on **#Somecode#** 's spot? And also, when my characters restores health points, I don't want them to exceed their max HP like 151/100 so is the code **if (plhp > 101) { plhp = 100; }** correct? Total newb here thanks :)

Comment: Grab yourself a C# book or find a tutorial online.  This is basic stuff....

Comment: Do your own homework - you are unlikely to learn C# well by posting homework questions and having other people answer them for you. Google is your friend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following will work:

```
int hitPoints = rdn.Next(10, 55);
zenhp -= hitPoints;
Console.WriteLine("Zen has taken " + hitPoints + " damage!");
```

Which is the same as:

```
Console.WriteLine("Zen has taken " + hitPoints.ToString() + " damage!");
```

For your second question, if the maximum HP is 100, then your code currently does not cater for HP = 101. You should have instead:

```
if (plhp >= 101) { plhp = 100; }
```

Or

```
if (plhp > 100) { plhp = 100; }
```